# regex: negative lookahead with multiline text

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have several files with text blocks like that:

```
  maxlength:
    maxlength_js: 500
    maxlength_js_label: 'Inhalt auf @limit Zeichen begrenzt, verbleibend: <strong>@remaining</strong>'
    maxlength_js_enforce: true
    maxlength_js_truncate_html: false
```

Sometimes *maxlength_js_enforce: true* is present sometimes not.
I want to add *maxlength_js_enforce: true* to all such maxlenght: blocks by find and replace.

I tried to find all *maxlength:* blocks without *maxlength_js_enforce* with a regex pattern with negative lookahead but somehow I can't get it working with multiple lines and no real limit for the end of such a block.

I have tried it with a pattern like that `(maxlength:(\s*.*))(?!enforce)`
Here is an example with a whole file with multiple occurences of such a block https://regexr.com/7mjh1
Make sure to open the whole file example to understand the problem.

Either it matches to many lines or not enough and even while "enforce" is present it is a match.
I think I don't get the concept correct and have problems with specifing the borders of such a block in the file, guess it must be really simple but don't get it.

Comment: Will you be using the regex in JavaScript or any other code?

Comment: *I want to add maxlength_js_enforce: true to all such maxlenght: blocks by find and replace.* With what tool?

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/8oPIpf/1) might work, but it depends on where you are using the regex and what exact text you have.

Comment: Since this is YAML, you might consider a YAML parser...

Comment: A sorry, just wanted to use the regex from the find and replace function in the Jetbrains IDE. The exact text is behind the link. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: So replace `(?m)^(\h*)maxlength:(?:\R\1(?!\h*maxlength_js_enforce:)(\h+).*)*$(?!\R\1\h)` with `$0\n$1$2maxlength_js_enforce: true`

Comment: Uuuh excelent! This works perfect. Have to sit down and study that. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)^(\h*)maxlength:(?:\R\1(?!\h*maxlength_js_enforce:)(\h+).*)*$(?!\R\1\h)
```

Then, you need to replace with

```
$0\n$1$2maxlength_js_enforce: true
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pVCYNt/1).

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - a `Pattern.MULTILINE` inline option
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\h*)` - Group 1: zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `maxlength:` - a text
- `(?:\R\1(?!\h*maxlength_js_enforce:)(\h+).*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\R` - any line break sequence
  - `\1` - Same value as in Group 1 (the indentation whitespace sequence)
  - `(?!\h*maxlength_js_enforce:)` - not followed with zero or more horizontal whitespace and then `maxlength_js_enforce:` text
  - `(\h+)` - Group 1: one or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
- `$` - end of the line...
- `(?!\R\1\h)` - that is not immediately followed with a line break, the same value as captured in Group 1 and then a single horizontal whitespace.

The `$0\n$1$2maxlength_js_enforce: true` replacement pattern replaces the matched text with itself (`$0`) and then adds a newline (`\n`), Group 1 value (`$1`), Group 2 value (`$2`) and then the `maxlength_js_enforce: true` text.

Answer (score 1):

I added the multiline flag to the pattern in order to use ^ for beginning of line. This will match in each group up to and including the optional existing key:

```
^((\x20*)maxlength:.*([\r\n]+\2\x20{2}(?!\x20*maxlength_js_enforce:).*)+)([\r\n]+\2\x20*maxlength_js_enforce:.*)?
```

You can replace with this to add/replace the setting you want:

```
$1\n$2  maxlength_js_enforce: true
```

This will also work to replace `maxlength_js_enforce: false` (although there isn't an example of this in the demo)